# query with calculations most efficient way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written the query below which works fine & produces the correct results. However I feel this is probably not terribly efficient as my SQL experience is quite limited.

The main thing that sticks out is where I calculate the nominal differences & price differences, these two lines.

```
1.   isnull(hld.Nominal, 0) - isnull(nav.Nominal, 0) NomDiff
2.   isnull((hld.Price / nav.LocalPrice - 1) * 100, 0)
```

Because I also have to put both these lines in the where condition, so the same calculations are being calculated twice. What is a better way of writing this query?

```
;WITH hld AS
(
    SELECT id,
           name,
           Nominal,
           Price
    FROM tblIH
),
nav AS
(
    SELECT id,
           name,
           Nominal,
           LocalPrice
    FROM tblNC
)
SELECT COALESCE(hld.id, nav.id) id,
       COALESCE(nav.name, hld.name) name,
       ISNULL(hld.Nominal, 0) HldNom,
       ISNULL(nav.Nominal, 0) NavNom,
       ISNULL(hld.Nominal, 0) - ISNULL(nav.Nominal, 0) NomDiff,
       ISNULL(hld.Price, 0) HldPrice,
       ISNULL(nav.LocalPrice, 0) NavPrice,
       ISNULL((hld.Price / nav.LocalPrice - 1) * 100, 0)
FROM hld
FULL OUTER JOIN nav ON hld.id = nav.id
WHERE ISNULL(hld.Nominal, 0) - ISNULL(nav.Nominal, 0) <> 0
    OR ISNULL((hld.Price / nav.LocalPrice - 1) * 100, 0) <> 0
```

Comment: I would suggest that you include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You coukd use COALESCE instead of ISNULL but thy will probably have the same performance. COALESCE is sometimes slightly better, and since you call INSULL many times you could gain some bit in performance

Comment: The calculation part you can include in the second CTE , then you can simply select or filter the calculated field as a column name in your final select query without further calculations.

Comment: @Antonio: ISNULL and COALESCE are the same, in most cases. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4277/630

Comment: @gbn not entirely true. As I said "they will probably have the same performance". It could depend on which SQL server Version he is using. AFAIK in some occasions COALESCE is slighly better than isnull...

And sicne he is calling ISNULL many times he should compare their use. Not that difficult and worth the work, in my opinion...

See: https://www.mssqltips.com/tipImages2/2689_Coalesce_IsNull_Perf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you select without where condition, you have result as table tmp, then you add where condition with column NomDiff and PriceDiff

```
;WITH hld AS
(
    SELECT id,
           name,
           Nominal,
           Price
    FROM tblIH
),
nav AS
(
    SELECT id,
           name,
           Nominal,
           LocalPrice
    FROM tblNC
)
select * 
from (SELECT COALESCE(hld.id, nav.id) id,
           COALESCE(nav.name, hld.name) name,
           ISNULL(hld.Nominal, 0) HldNom,
           ISNULL(nav.Nominal, 0) NavNom,
           ISNULL(hld.Nominal, 0) - ISNULL(nav.Nominal, 0) NomDiff,
           ISNULL(hld.Price, 0) HldPrice,
           ISNULL(nav.LocalPrice, 0) NavPrice,
           ISNULL((hld.Price / nav.LocalPrice - 1) * 100, 0) PriceDiff
    FROM hld
    FULL OUTER JOIN nav ON hld.id = nav.id) tmp
where NomDiff <> 0 or PriceDiff <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The calculation part you can include in the second CTE, then you can simply select or filter the calculated field as a normal column in your final select query, without further calculations.